# Cannot Update General Fields With Workflow In CRM Dynamics

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create a workflow in Microsoft Dynamics 2013, this workflow creates a contact whenever a lead is created. I'm trying to move over the lead email. However there are some "General" fields that it will not let me interact with when I create the work flow. Email is one of those fields. Anything that's an "Additional Field" can have a value added. I can't add any value, dynamic or otherwise to any of the General Fields. 
Does anyone know if there is a setting I need to change on the fields or there is something I'm doing wrong? I don't know how to get that Email field to accept values for this workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was a form with those fields set to Read-Only. There were several forms, so it was a matter of finding which was the culprit.